# Forcing $.when to return a variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have been struggling for quiet sometime now with conversion of file chunks to binary data and have come to this point

```
for(....){
    $.when(chunkBinary(chunk[i][j])).done(function(result){ chunkInBinary = result;console.log(chunkInBinary);} )
 }
```

Now I want to be able to use the value chunkInBinary outside the done function. Something like this:

```
for(....){
    $.when(chunkBinary(chunk[i][j])).done(function(result){ chunkInBinary = result;} )
    console.log(chunkInBinary);
 }
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

My chunkBinary function returns a promise.

Comment: you can't do that if `chunkBinary()` returns a unresolved promise

Comment: tell us why do you want to do that then we can try to see whether there is any other solution to the probelem

Comment: Well I am resolving it inside the function and when I log it in done function I am getting what I expect to see. All I need is that variables data to be available outside the done function, if possible.

Comment: I need to make a service call to post that data to the server.

Comment: Before you continue, you need to understand how asynchronous code works. You can't rely on the order of your code when working with asynchronous operations.

Comment: Isnt done function being called only after the completion of the $.when function? (which has the promise returned to it) ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is already correct.. by  creating a variable without the var keyword, u r literally creating a global variable. So now you can access the chuckinbinary variable outside any function as it is in global scope. This is not good practise as u r  cluttering ur global work space.

Comment: U should write in English, not in ur own slang ^^